# PHP/SQLite Push down row if Primary Key is taken

Tags: php, sqlite, primary-key

I'm making a HighScore class that saves the highscores in a SQLite database. If more than one player has got the same score, then I'd like the new score to be placed above the old one in the list, pushing the old one down one row.

The table consists of columns "rwId", "Score" and "Name". At first, I made Score the "PRIMARY KEY", so that the list would be sorted (backwards) by the score. But then I thought it would be better to make the rowId the Primary Key and set this ID when the score is saved. This way, the list would be in the right order, making it easier to delete the lowest score later.

Either way, If the primary key has already been taken by a previous score, the old score and all rows below it in the table needs to be pushed down one row.

Is this possible to do?

This is what I've got so far (which isn't much to show for):

```
  public function CheckRank($score) {
  $this->stmt = $this->sql->prepare('SELECT score, rowId FROM highscore ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10;');
  $this->stmt->execute();
  $this->res = $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


//Check what the 10 highest scores are an what row in the DB they're on
$i=0;
foreach ($this->res as $key => $value) {
  $scorearray[$value['rowId']] = $value['score'];
  $i++;
}

//Check if this score has already been set. If so, push old scores down and insert the new one
$rowsearch = array_search ($score, $scorearray); 
if($rowsearch)
 {
// HOW?
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the key? Better yet, why do you want your database to be in order? You're already using an `ORDER BY` clause in your query, is that not good enough?

Comment: Mainly for easy removing of scores that doesn't fit the scoreboard (remove all scores below 10th place). But maybe this is overkill. Should be possible to do the same thing without sorting the database..

Comment: Just use a delete with your same select as part of the condition: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fab88/13

Comment: For deleting, you could do it in <=2 queries. First, find the record with the tenth highest score: `"SELECT score FROM highscore ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10;"`. Then delete everything below that one (here, `tenth` is the tenth highest score`"DELETE FROM highscore WHERE score < ".tenth['score'].";"`. You can do the same thing in a single query, like @prodigitalson shows in his fiddle.

Comment: Thanks guys! I ended up with a mix of both of your examples. I think both versions should work very well, but I'm having other problems with my code (can't get 'WHERE score > $val' to find anything) , so I can't really test them yet.